# Parsing classes with GroovyShell

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a groovy script that need to run a method inside a class inside an external groovy script.
I know how to run a method within an external groovy script:

```
new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'foo.groovy' ) ).with {
    method()
  }
```

But what if the method is inside a class? I tried this but it gave me an error.

```
new GroovyShell().parse( new File( 'foo.groovy' ) ).with {
    theclass.method()
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a sample `foo.groovy`? Anyway, `theclass` seems to need to be instantiated

Comment: `theclass.newInstance().method()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java reflection to create new instance of a Class that is located in another script:

```
File sourceFile = new File("D:\\anoutherScript.groovy")
//here you have to update your classloader with external script
getClass().getClassLoader().addURL(sourceFile.toURI().toURL())
GroovyObject obj = Class.forName("ClassInAnotherObject").newInstance()
obj.doSth()
```

Script in your external file would be like that:

```
class ClassInAnotherObject{
    def doSth(){
    }
}
```

but there could be more classes in script file, also some more instructions and method call. Just like normal groovy script.