# GroovyShell().parse passing parameters

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I have a groovy script that needs to parse a class from an external groovy script. I am not sure how to pass parameters. Here is what works:

Groovy script I am running is using this line to parse the external class from external.groovy:

```
new GroovyShell().parse(new File('External.groovy'))
```

Here  is what  external.groovy looks like:

```
class External {
    public external() {
        println "Hello"
    }
}
```

It works.

The problem I am having, I cant find a way to pass parameters to the external method. Here is what external.groovy should look like:

```
class External {
    public external(String name) {
        println name
    }
}
```

How do I add parameters to the running script:

```
new GroovyShell().parse(new File('external.groovy')) //need to include the 'Name' parameter to this
```

Comment: What is the use case? Have no idea how to handle it but maybe it could be done a little different.

Comment: here my answer from another post, maybe helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090660/parsing-classes-with-groovyshell/24095060#24095060

Comment: Is it `external` or `External`?

Answer (score 5):

1. `parse` only parses your file and doesn't execute it
2. you have to call `run` as well
3. you need to instantiate your file AND you need to call your method and give it the parameter
4. you need to give the parameter via an `Binding` object

Here is the class and the call

```
class External {
     public external(String name) {
        println name
    }
}
new External.external(somename)
```

and then

```
def bindings = new Binding()
bindings.setVariable("somename", "mrhaki")
def shell = new GroovyShell(bindings)
shell.parse(new File('external.groovy'))
shell.run()
```

Comment: new External.external(somename) these days gives.. unable to resolve class External.external