# Can you pass variables to Groovy's evaluate(File file)?

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to pass scope variables to Groovy's evaluate(File file)? And therefore to access variable `a` in the file OtherScript.groovy listed below?

FirstScript.groovy:

```
a = 4
evaluate(new File('OtherScript.groovy'))
println 'I can see b = ${b}'
```

OtherScript.groovy:

```
b = 2 * a
```

When running this example the following exception is raised: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: a for class: OtherScript`

Comment: Which script are you executing? Calling `groovy FirstScript.groovy` should produce the expected result. The error you show suggests that you are calling `groovy OtherScript.groovy`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use some sort of Bean Scripting Framework (BSF) which supported by Groovy,
Groovy implement BSF in `org.codehaus.groovy.bsf.GroovyEngine`,here is a quick example to use `BSFManager`

```
@Grab('org.apache.bsf:bsf-api:3.1')

import org.apache.bsf.BSFManager

BSFManager manager = new BSFManager()
manager.declareBean("xyz", 4, Integer.class)
Object answer = manager.eval("groovy", "test.groovy", 0, 0, "xyz + 1")
assert 5 == answer
```

Example from the [groovy doc](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.1/html/documentation/).
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154876/groovyshell-parse-passing-parameters) uses `GroovyShell` which is another possible solution for your example.

code tested with Groovy v2.5.1. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

your scripts are fine except one thing:

the string with `println` should be doublequoted to interpolate expressions

so, if you have

**FirstScript.groovy**

```
a = 4
evaluate(new File('OtherScript.groovy'))
println "I can see b = ${b}"
```

**OtherScript.groovy**

```
b = 2 * a
```

then the following command line works:

```sh
groovy FirstScript.groovy
```

and prints:

```
I can see b = 8
```